# Gender neutral noun for brotherhood / sisterhood?

Tags: grammatical-gender, gender-neutral

Example 1: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_White_Brotherhood

Example 2: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brotherhood_of_Eternal_Love

---

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/brotherhood?s=t

#### Any other ideas?

> association
>
> fraternity
>
> guild
>
> kinship
>
> affiliation
>
> alliance
>
> clan
>
> clique
>
> community
>
> comradeship
>
> confederacy
>
> coterie
>
> fellowship
>
> league
>
> society
>
> union

Comment: This has been asked before. 'Kinship' isn't used for say 'fraternity / league' in any of the dictionaries I've checked in.

Comment: Gender is a matter of families and birth and the propagation of humanity by procreation. I agree with the comments on the previous duplicate that organisations wishing to be 'gender neutral' would not want to use any familial descriptions at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Siblinghood**

The state of being a sibling

> https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/siblinghood

Comment: OP clearly goes on to restrict the sense required to the organisational usage. (Which makes this a duplicate.)

Comment: I don't. The public does.  Arguing 'X ought to be allowed by analogy with Y' soon brings you into trouble. Why don't we consider as standard  'John has sadly kicked the pail', 'a boat of the desert', 'Sibling Francis', 'personhunt', 'The Glasgow Kinship of ... (or similar)', .... References on ELU should show that usages are standardly used, not that there is an argument that they ought to be in someone's opinion.

Comment: On looking at the other duplicate, I agree with the OP of the previous question that true 'gender neutrality' does not attempt to derive anything familial in order to express it within an organisational context. Which would make the above question wrong in the first place.

Comment: I've already close-voted. I often wonder why others argue that questions are wrong but don't close-vote.

Comment: I did not realise I had that option. I shall research that. Thank you.